# unable to find view with tag

Tags: swift, viewwillappear, viewwithtag

In my viewWillAppear() I create a label and give it a tag. When another condition is met, I try to remove the label, but for some reason, that is not working and the label is still in the view. I must be doing something wrong...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    var label: UILabel?

    // Add label if there are no recipes
    if (recipeBook.recipesArr.count == 0) {

        label = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel
        //label?.tag = 123 // arbitrary num

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/3, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
        label?.text = "Add A Recipe"
        label?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        label?.font = label?.font.withSize(36)
        label?.textAlignment = .center

        self.view.addSubview(label!)
    }

    else {

        // remove it
        if let foundLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(123) {
            foundLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            print("Couldn't find label with tag in view")
        }

    }

}
```

I didn't realize in this line `label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/3, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))` I was creating a new label which has a default tag of 0. Changed it to `label?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/3, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)` so that I'm not creating a new label and everything is working fine. Silly mistake.

Comment: You are getting the label by tag in `viewWillAppear` and in the next line you overwrite it with a new `UILabel` instance with the default tag 0. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think it is.  If your recipesArr is empty (or more accurately the count is zero) you are trying to find a label/view with the tag 123.  That is then ignored and you create a new label but don't give it a tag.

What you need to do is assign the label you create the tag 123 after you create it like this:

```
label?.tag = 123
```

Then you will have created the label and set it's tag so it can then subsequently be found.

Comment: Ahhh thank you. The noob in me didn't realize the way I was creating the label with UILabel(frame: CGRect(...)) creates a new label.

Answer (score 0):

you are recreating the label after the line `label = UILabel(frame: CGRect`

you can create the label programmatically like so without optionals:

```
lazy var recipeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/3, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    label.tag = 123
    label.text = "Add A Recipe"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

then add it to your subview with [iOS 9+ constraints if needed](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout):

```
 self.view.addSubview(recipeLabel)
```

then you can access the view anywhere by simply referencing the view `recipeLabel` or by the `.tag` property if you desire.